# Trigger after update orderline

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

im trying to create a trigger to set a order date to system date once all the items in the order have been dispatched.

we have a OrderHeader table with order_id and order_completed. This will have 1 row per order

We then have OrderLine table with orderline_order with a foreign key to OrderHeader. This table can have multiple rows for the same orderline_order (so multiple items for a order)
Orderline has a field in it orderline_fulfilled which is either a 'Y' or 'N'

I want a trigger to update the order_completed to sysdate when all orderline_fulfilled are 'Y' for that order. I currently got to the statement below, but how would I ensure im only checking the orderline_fulfilled is 'Y' for that orderline_order if that makes sense?

```
 create or repalce trigger Order_complete
  after update of Orderline_fulfilled
  on val354_orderline
  begin update val354_orderheader join val354_orderline on (Order_id = Orderline_order)
  set Order_completed = sysdate 
  where Orderline_fulfilled
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ORDER_COMPLETE
  AFTER UPDATE OF ORDERLINE_FULFILLED
    ON VAL354_ORDERLINE
BEGIN
  UPDATE VAL354_ORDERHEADER h
    SET h.ORDER_COMPLETED = 'Y'
    WHERE h.ORDER_COMPLETED = 'N' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM VAL354_ORDERLINE l
                        WHERE l.ORDERLINE_ORDER = h.ORDER_ID AND
                              l.ORDERLINE_FULFILLED = 'N');
END ORDER_COMPLETE;
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Tried this with a few alterations, but keep getting a "string not found" error